# CSS3 Text Pushes Div Block Underneath Downward- Need Containment Of Rows

Tags: html, css

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EJluF

It seems the text pushes the  blocks out of alignment. How can I stop this? For instance, "Server Back Up" does it real bad. I tried to place each row in it's own block, but the containment is not working/effective. I don't see in chromium debug where "Server Back Up" is pushing the clock div below it down...so that is weird why it is doing it.

Here is the CSS3 text portion that may be of some help:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


#row1 {
    display: block;
    width: 1600px;
    height: 230px;
}

#row2 {
    display: block;
    width: 1600px;
    height: 230px;
}

#row3 {
    display: block;
    width: 1600px;
    height: 230px;
}

.zentext {
    font-family: yo2;
    text-shadow: 1px 8px 1px #000;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 200%;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    color: cyan;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add to

```
.zentext {
position: absolute;
}
```